# How can I control the order of items in the Components array?

Tags: delphi, components

I developed a small application in Delphi with TEdit components on it.[image]
I used this function to validate if the component fields are not empty.

```
function TF_config.Validatefields:boolean;
var 
  i : integer;
begin
 for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
 begin
   if (Components[i]is TEdit) then
   begin
      if ((TEdit(Components[i]).Text) ='') then
      begin
        MessageDlg('Enter data in all the fields',mtWarning,[MBOK],0);
        TEdit(Components[i]).SetFocus;
        result := false;
        exit;
     end;             
   end;  //end for TEdit
 end;    //end component count 
 result := true;
end;
```

Now I have to add one more component
[image]
The order in which the function checks for data if valid is 
*ID->Name->Address->Phone->Age*. But I want it to be *ID->Name->Address->Age->Phone*.
I tried solving it deleting the *Phone* Edit component and later add it after adding the *Age* Edit component.Or using the *Phone* Edit component for *Age* and add new Edit component  for *Phone*. This is easier for few components, but becomes tedious when having many of them. 
So I was wondering if we could arrange the components in a manner that suits us. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest putting the controls in your own list/array, then you have full control over its content and ordering, and can loop through it when needed.  This also ensures that you touch only the controls you are actually interested in and not wasting time touching other controls that you are not interested in, and it also allows the VCL to maintain its own ordering of its own internal lists as it sees fit.

```
type
  TF_config = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  ...
  private
    EditFields: array[0..4] of TEdit;
    function ValidateFields: Boolean; 
  ...
  end;

procedure TF_config.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EditFields[0] := IdEdit;
  EditFields[1] := NameEdit;
  EditFields[2] := AddressEdit;
  EditFields[3] := AgeEdit;
  EditFields[4] := PhoneEdit;
end; 

function TF_config.ValidateFields: Boolean; 
var  
  i : integer; 
begin 
  for i := Low(EditFields) to High(EditFields) do 
  begin 
    if EditFields[i].GetTextLen = 0 then 
    begin 
      MessageDlg('Enter data in all the fields', mtWarning, [MBOK], 0); 
      EditFields[i].SetFocus; 
      Result := False; 
      Exit; 
    end;              
  end;
  Result := True; 
end;
```

**Update**: If you have multiple types of controls that you need to validate, you can do this instead:

```
type 
  TF_config = class(TForm) 
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
  ... 
  private 
    Fields: array[0..4] of TControl; 
    function ValidateFields: Boolean;  
  ... 
  end; 

procedure TF_config.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  Fields[0] := ...; 
  Fields[1] := ...; 
  ...
  Fields[4] := ...; 
end;  

function TF_config.ValidateFields: Boolean;  
var   
  i : Integer;  
  ctrl: TControl;
begin  
  Result := True;
  for i := Low(Fields) to High(Fields) do  
  begin  
    ctrl := Fields[i];
    if ctrl is TCustomEdit then // handles both TEdit and TMemo
    begin  
      if TCustomEdit(ctrl).GetTextLen = 0 then  
      begin  
        Result := False;
        Break;
      end;               
    end;
    if ctrl is TComboBox then
    begin  
      if TComboBox(ctrl).ItemIndex = -1 then  
      begin  
        Result := False;
        Break;
      end;               
    end;
    ... and so on ...
  end;
  if not Result then
  begin
    MessageDlg('Enter data in all the fields', mtWarning, [MBOK], 0);  
    ctrl.SetFocus;  
  end;
end;
```

Comment: nice solution, but having memo fields,Combo boxes,etc will lead to more arrays of components possibly more space consumption.

Comment: Not really.  Even with more types of controls, using your own list is still preferred.  And you can use a single list holding `TControl` pointers and just type-cast them when needed, just as the original code was doing, but at least the ordering of the list will still be what you want it to be, and you still don't have to waste time looking at all of the other controls that don't apply to validation.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `TabOrder` property for ordering and `FindNextControl` method for moving between controls.

Comment: Right. I think that the assumption is valid that you want your checks done in the order in which they are traversed at run-time when editing.

Answer (score 4):

1. In the IDE, press Alt+F12 or right-click on the form and select "View as Text" to open the form's resource (.dfm)
2. Rearrange your components (cut&paste) as required. The order in which they appear in the resource is the order in which they will be listed in the form's `Components` property at runtime.

Comment: Is this the only way? Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: You could also rewrite your code to not rely on the order of the `Components` at all.

Comment: Seems like there is no easy way out here.

Comment: @TOndrej: instead of altering the DFM manually, you can right-click on the Form Designer and select the "Creation Order" option instead.  Then you can arrange the controls as needed using a visual list.

Comment: @RemyLebeau AFAIK creation order is for non-visual components only, isn't it?

Comment: "Creation Order" applies to non-visual, yes. I thought it was for all components.  Looks like "Tab Order" applies to the visual components.  So either way, still no need to edit the DFM manually.

Comment: "Tab Order", on the other hand, can become more complicated with multiple levels of parent/child controls (e.g. panels on panels or frames). It also assumes that the order of validation should be the same as the tab order, which is questionable. My preferred solution would be to keep your own ordered list of controls to be validated, as in your answer. The question, however, was how to control the order of `Components`.